# Django class based views: variable across classes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a mixin called **GroupAwareMixin** in a **mixins.py** file:

```
class GroupAwareMixin(object):
    group = None

    def get_group(self):
        self.group = self.bridge.get_group()

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.group:
            self.get_group()
```

In the **views.py** file I have the following ListView which inherits from the above GroupAwareMixin:

```
class ChatListView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupAwareMixin, ListView):
   model = Chat
   template_name = 'chat/home.html'
```

Further I have a **Chat** class in my views.py file, where I would like to access the **group** variable from the GroupAwareMixin class above. How I am able to access the group variable in the Chat class?

```
class Chat(ws.WS, ChatListView):
    def on_message(self, websocket, msg):
        slug = self.group
```

I tried to inherit from ChatListView, but the **self.group** in the **Chat** class is None.

The **LoginRequiredMixin** defines the following:

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            if self.raise_exception:
                raise PermissionDenied  # return a forbidden response
            else:
                return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path(),
                                     self.get_login_url(),
                                     self.get_redirect_field_name())

        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Are you calling `self.get_group()` anywhere? And does that function ever set `self.group` (rather than just the local variable `group`)?

Comment: I updated the GroupAwareMixin... made some typing mistakes before.

Comment: That seems fragile. Are you sure that `LoginRequiredMixin` and `ws.WS` don't themselves define `dispatch`?

Comment: added the LoginRequiredMixin

Comment: The dispatch method in the `GroupAwareMixin` gets definitely called , because I debugged it and the group gets assigned a group.

Comment: Does dispatch get called before on_message fires?

Could you make group a `property` instead

Comment: `Dispatch` gets called the first time I visit the page... but when `on_message` fires I am not able to call `dispatch` any more, because I have no `request`, `args` & `kwargs` in the `on_message` function. So when `dispatch` gets called the first time I should somehow save the value of the `group` variable so that I can access it later in the `on_message` function. Any ideas how accomplish that?

Comment: you can't do this, this way; each view is run in different context and you have no chance to share variables between them, you should have some kind of getter for the bridge